# Getting "compiled with warnings" for using regular expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

iI'm getting compiled with warnings alert.
this is the message.

`Compiled with warnings`.

```
./src/components/register/register.js
  Line 5:  Unnecessary escape character: \$  no-useless-escape
  Line 5:  Unnecessary escape character: \^  no-useless-escape
  Line 5:  Unnecessary escape character: \*  no-useless-escape
```

this is the code on line 5. I'm using it to check if a password contains 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number, 1 special character and if its longer than 8 characters.

```
const passwordRegex = RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/);
```

I'm wondering why am I getting this alert? and how do I make it go away?

Comment: Well, the warnings are telling you what's wrong. Why not just heed what they say? The escapes they mention are unnecessary (because they occur inside a range).

Comment: I can appreciate that - we're all new to things are some time. But in your case the warnings are telling you exactly what's wrong. Duskwuff's answer expounds on why these characters don't need escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is pointing out -- correctly -- that the characters `$`, `^`, and `*` do not need to be escaped in the character class `[!@#$%^&*]`. The only characters with special meanings in this context are `[`, `]`, `-`, and `\`.